# Can't locate IO/Socket/Socks.pm in @INC

Tags: perl

Возникает ошибка, указанная в заголовке. Как этот модуль установить?

```
use IO::Socket::Socks;
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 2):

cpan> install IO::Socket::Socks

Comment: Постарайтесь отвечать более развернуто